# Having grading system with no output

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I've been trying to make grading system with this code but it has no outcome and I get empty lists. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
def grades_data():
    import csv
    global idlist
    global namelist
    global finalscorelist
    for i in range(len(idlist)):
        if int(finalscorelist[i])>=90 and int(finalscorelist[i])<=100:
               grades.append("A")
               continue
        elif int(finalscorelist[i])>=75 and int(finalscorelist[i])<90:
            grades.append("B")
            continue
        elif int(finalscorelist[i])>=60 and int(finalscorelist[i])<75:
            grades.append("c")
            continue
        elif int(finalscorelist[i])>=50 and int(finalscorelist[i])<60:
            grades.append("D")
            continue
        else:
            grades.append("F")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")   #to make a border 
    print("id\tname\tgrades")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")    #to make a border 
    for (idlist,namelist,grades) in zip (idlist,namelist,grades):
        print(str(idlist)+"\t"+str(namelist)+"\t\t"+str(grades))
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")    #to make a border
```

Output:

```
id  name    grades
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not detail the layout of your csv file but I imagine it to be something like this.

```
id,name,score
1,"Steve",90
2,"Jill",92
3,"Billy",100
4,"Sara",75
5,"Bob",80
6,"Julie",89
7,"Wes",60
8,"Andy",74
9,"Jack",59
10,"Greta",50
11,"Wilma",48
```

Script

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("scores.csv")

grades = {
    "A": (90, 101),
    "B": (75, 90),
    "C": (60, 75),
    "D": (50, 60),
    "F": (0, 50),
}

df["grade"] = None
for grade in grades:
    idx = df[
        df["score"].between(grades[grade][0], grades[grade][1], inclusive="left")
    ].index
    df.loc[idx, "grade"] = grade

print(df)
df.to_csv("grades.csv")
```

You will need to pip install pandas to your working environment. This script loads the "scores.csv" file from the working directory, creates a grades dictionary, assign an empty grade column, cycles through the grades dictionary assigning the grades based on the grades dictionary and scores, and finally prints the grades dataframe, and saves a grades.csv file.

[image: Output]